# Unable to connect PHP STOMP to remote ActiveMQ

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

Code

```
try {
    $stomp = new Stomp('tcp://xx:xxx:xxx:xxx:61616','admin','admin'); 
    // connection to remote server
} catch(StompException $e) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Result

```
Connection failed: Server is not responding
```

The above code works fine for `localhost` or intranet but not for outside IP.

The connection to the same server using java code works, but not when using PHP STOMP.

Comment: You would have to contact the administrator of the server having the outside IP.

Comment: but by using java code i am able to connect to same server

Answer (score 0):

Typically the port 61616 is the OpenWire port for the broker and as such a STOMP client will not be able to connect to it.  If you've configured that as STOMP and still cannot get to it from outside the local network then it is likely a firewall issue or some other network policy inhibiting the ability of the client to get through.  There isn't much anyone outside your administration can do since we don't know your configuration or network topology.